# Which job boards do you like and have used?

Tags: website

A job board is not really an app, it's just a list, simply speaking. Anyway, most of these are applications from the implementer's view.

- Which job boards did you like and why?
- Which job boards did you use and found useful in the past?

Background: I am doing a short report on the internet job board landscape at the moment, so links or short answers would be a great help for me!

Comment: I'm torn between voting to close and thinking it should be CW.

Comment: Made it CW; admit it reads a little like an edge case.

Comment: [www.craigslist.org](http://www.craigslist.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jobster](http://www.jobster.com) has a nice user interface and experience; not sure about its effectiveness.

[Stack Overflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) rocks :)

[LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/jobs) has a good jobs section

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you'd consider it a job board in the traditional sense, but:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

I have had great success with our state run [Department of Workforce Services job board](http://jobs.utah.gov) for both finding new jobs and hiring full or part time candidates. They are 100% free and get 10-100 times the job postings that other sites do. Most other states have an [equivalent site](http://www.jobbankinfo.org/), which are great resources for both employees and employees.

Answer (score 0):

[TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/)'s [CrunchBoard](http://www.crunchboard.com/jobs/) is an excellent resource.